Import ZFS Pool - Created by TrueNAS Scale
Can I import/mount a ZFS pool that was created with TrueNAS Scale in Ubuntu? As I am going away from TrueNAS and don't want to loose all the data/media I have in that pool.
Thanks :)

Welcome to AskUbuntu! TrueNAS scale is based on Debian Linux, so you should be able to mount the ZFS pool so long as you have all of the storage devices. It should be possible to test this by booting with the Ubuntu installation media, using “Try Ubuntu”, then mounting it in the terminal.

I just went ahead and tried! And yes it worked like a charm! No data loss what so ever. Anyway thank you! I just had to install the zfsutilities.

@StianTofte please write up an answer to your own question, preferably with commands included. Thanks.
